# How can I wait for nextElementSibling to exist then execute my function on on it?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I want to execute a function when the nextElementSibling exists for a given node.

So in my dom I have nodes a and b.

```html
<section>
   <div id="a">...</div>
   <div id="b">...</div>
</section>
```

I have a third-party script that is dynamically injecting new div nodes into a node at an unknown future time.

```html
<section>
   <div id="a">...</div>
   <div id="b">...</div>
   <div id="c">...</div>
   <div id="d">...</div>
</section>
```

I can target element b and perform a function with it. I want that function to say "when my node 'b' has a nextElementSibling, call function X with that node ('c').

I really want to say 'When element b exists, execute function X(a)', 'When element c exists, execute function X(b)', 'When element d exists, execute function X(c)'.

---

I found a function for waiting for an element to exist based on its selector.

```js
function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}
```

However this requires a selector to work but there isn't a selector for "my next sibling". Could it work somehow to detect the next element sibling existing?

Comment: I think you need to observer the [parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) of the selector.  And then in the callback check for [mutation.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord/type) = "childList" and then use [mutation.previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord/previousSibling).  I ran a quick test and seemed to work as expected.

Comment: "*I found a function…*" - where did you find that? Please attribute the author and cite your source.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to rewrite that function not to use `document.querySelector` but rather check whether your target has a `.nextSiblingElement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bergi for pointing me in the right direction. I was over thinking it and trying to use a selector.

```js
function waitForNextSibling(me) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (me.nextElementSibling) {
        return resolve(me.nextElementSibling);
    }

    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
        if (me.nextElementSibling) {
            resolve(me.nextElementSibling);
            observer.disconnect();
        }
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
  });
}
```

usage

```
waitForNextSibling(me).then((next) => {

})
```